# "devota a vários" vs "devota de vários"

Tags: preposições

Qual é maneira correta: "devota a vários" ou "devota de vários"
Eu encontrei seguinte frase:

> Vovó era devota a vários santos.

Nesse site:

https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/regencia-alguns-nomes.htm

Procurando na internet quase não encontrei a forma "devota a vários".

Comment: Eu não tenho a certeza, mas pra mim a devoção parte da pessoa para a outra pessoa, símbolo, entidade. Por sua vez, soa melhor "devota a vários". Pois "de" faz soar que a devoção vem da "entidade" e não para a "entidade". Tipo a diferença entre "to" e "from" no inglês

Comment: Realizando busca no google: "devota a vários" aparece 10 resultado, contra 37.700 resultado de  "devota de vários", esta sendo usado uma matéria da editora abril https://vejasp.abril.com.br/cidades/janaina-paschoal-impeachment-advogada eu fique na dúvida porque texto "devota a varios"  apareceu em site site educacional.

Comment: Agora parando para pensar "Eu não entendo como uma pessoa pode ser torcedora de vários times(de futebol)." Então consigo ver casos onde ambos funcionariam

Answer (score 1):

*Devoto **de*** é mais comum que *devoto **a***, mas ambos estão corretos, conforme inclusive a própria [fonte](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/regencia-alguns-nomes.htm) da postagem original:

> **Devoto**
>   Preposição - a; de
>
> Os fiéis são devotos de Santo Antônio.
>   Vovó era devota a vários santos.

E também de acordo com o [Recanto das Letras](https://www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/2922796) e o site do [senado brasileiro](https://www12.senado.leg.br/manualdecomunicacao/redacao-e-estilo/estilo/regencia-nominal) (!). Os dicionários que chequei que mencionam a regência citam, talvez por concisão, apenas "de", e.g., o Michaelis:

> Um devoto de santo Expedito.

Vale notar o uso do artigo quando usado no sentido de *apreciador*, [por exemplo](http://www.aulete.com.br/devoto):

> **3**. Indivíduo devoto: devoto de santa Luzia.
>   **4**. Amigo, apreciador (devoto da arte)